# Stream reponse is getting printed on console while downloading file with AJAX Post

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, file, stream

I want to download MS Word file with an AJAX post request.

So here is my Java code

```
 response.setContentType("application/ms-word");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+childName+".docx");
 OutputStream opStream = response.getOutputStream();
```

The service name is `"/getAdmissionAgreement"` and it is post request. Now this is how I am downloading the file using ajax post request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,   
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        alert('got response');
        window.open(response);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error occurred while opening fax template' + getAjaxErrorString(textStatus, errorThrown));
    }
});
```

Now the problem is that the stream is coming but it is getting displayed in the browser's console and not coming as an downloadable file.

Comment: You can't download a file via AJAX. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax) for more information.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  Thanks for your reply. So how can we download it with post request. Is there any other way.

Comment: possible duplicated thread 
you need to refer here [how to download using ajax][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 1):

After Ajax successfully executed u can append dynamic link with file .

```
var a = $("<a>").attr("href", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8rHf.png").attr("download", 

 "img.png").appendTo("body");
  //force click on link 
  a[0].click()
```

or set,

```
window.location="path"
```